# Frequency response function from pyFRF

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I am analyzing data from experimental modal diagnostics (Roving hammer testing). My input data are records of acceleration and external force in time domain. Already transformed these to frequency domain with FFT and plots looks as expected.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIIJ2.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqVMW.png)

Now i need to compute and plot FRF (Frequency response function). I am using pyFRF package with code below (this is my data fed to example from pyFRF documentation)

```
from pyFRF import FRF
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyExSi

# data import
skiprow_list = [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
column_list = np.arange(1,15)

data = pd.read_csv("2024_01_03_WTB_drgania/a12.CSV",
                    delimiter=';',
                    decimal=',',
                    skiprows=skiprow_list,
                    usecols=column_list)

t = data[['C1:  Time[s]']]                  # time
a = data[['C1:  [m/s^2]']]                  # acceleration (acc sensor)
p = data[['C7:  [N]']]                      # force (hammer)


# date frame to 1D arrays
t = t.values.flatten()
a = a.values.flatten()
p = p.values.flatten()


N = len(t)
dt = (t[N-1] - t[0])/N                      # time step
fs = 1/dt                                   # sampling frequency
f0 = fs/N 

freq_syn = np.arange(0.0, 2000, f0)
omega = 2 * np.pi * freq_syn


# create an object
frf_object = FRF(sampling_freq=int(fs), exc=p, resp=a, resp_type='a', frf_type='H1')

# get frf
H1_pyFRF = frf_object.get_FRF()  # returns the requested FRF estimator matrix of shape (response DOF, excitation DOF, frequency points)
freq_pyFRF= frf_object.get_f_axis()  # returns frequency series
H1_pyFRF.shape  # single input, single output (SISO) system


plt.semilogy(freq_pyFRF[1:], np.abs(H1_pyFRF)[0,0,1:], color="b", label='pyFRF')
plt.xlim(left=0, right=2000)
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('FRF H1')
plt.legend();
```

Graph does not look like it should and im getting error

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  self.frf_conversion = np.power(-1.j / self.get_w_axis(), 2)
```

Could You please give me some hits what im doing wrong? I am a total beginner in both programming and signal analysis so please excuse me.

End results should look more less like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izyxd.png)

Comment: Could you providfe full stack trace? Because now we must guess on which line of your code the error occurred. If for some reason this actually *is* full stack trace, then try debug line by line and tell us on which line program stopped.

Comment: @dankal 
Stack trace: 
`runfile('C:/Users/Tomasz/Desktop/Stanowisko badawcze raport/PY/FRF.py', wdir='C:/Users/Tomasz/Desktop/Stanowisko badawcze raport/PY')
C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyFRF.py:308: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  self.frf_conversion = np.power(-1.j / self.get_w_axis(), 2)
C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyFRF.py:308: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  self.frf_conversion = np.power(-1.j / self.get_w_axis(), 2)`

Comment: This does not help, try debugging to see at which line of *your* code it occurs. Also, you've wrote that grapth does not look like it should. But you haven't shown what it currently looks like.

Comment: There is no error in my code as far as i understand, error occurs inside pyFRF, it looks like i feed it with wrong type/kind of data or i defined something wrong. I think there is no problem with code itself but with my understanding of this method, i get exaclty the same values for H1 and H2 estimators
here are the graphs: https://imgur.com/a/D6v6hIq

Comment: I suggest making simple toy example, create any signal with full spectrum (like gaussian noise), then scale it down/up by 10 or so to make a response, then check if FRF function gives you nice flat plot